# $f : \mathbb{C} -> \mathbb{C} f(z) = x^2 + axy + by^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find $a,b$ from $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C},\ f(z) = x^2 + axy + by^2$ for every $z = x + iy$ from $\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$

I've tried to derivate $f$ with respect to $z$ conjugate using $\frac{1}{2}(f_x' + f_y') = 0$
but i get $x = y = 0$ after solving the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\mathrm{Re}\,a+i\,\mathrm{Im}\,a$ and $b=\mathrm{Re}\,b+i\,\mathrm{Im}\,b$,
so
$$u(x,y)=\mathrm{Re}\,f(z)=x^2+\mathrm{Re}\,a\,xy+\mathrm{Re}\,b\,y^2,$$
$$v(x,y)=\mathrm{Im}\,f(z)= \mathrm{Im}\,a\,xy+\mathrm{Im}\,b\,y^2.$$
Let $f$ be entire function. Then Cauchy - Riemann equations hold on $\mathbb{R}^2$:

$u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$ for all  $x,\,y$

giving you:
$$2x+\mathrm{Re}\,a\,y=\mathrm{Im}\,a\,x+2\mathrm{Im}\,b\,y,$$
$$\mathrm{Re}\,a\,x+2\mathrm{Re}\,b\,y=-\mathrm{Im}\,a\,y.$$
So $$\mathrm{Im}\,a=2,~\mathrm{Re}\,a=2\mathrm{Im}\,b,~\mathrm{Re}\,a=0,~2\mathrm{Re}\,b=-\mathrm{Im}\,a$$
i.e. $a=2i,\,b=-1$ and $f(z)=z^2$ (which is clearly entire function).